# Writing into a file in a streaming way and stop when we reach a given memory file size

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes, streamly

Let's say I want to save a stream of `MyItem` into a file (in JSON for example). I would like to stop when the file reach a certain size limit in bytes. 
I would like to do it in Haskell... streaming is not the issue for me it's more how to get the file size information after each item put into this file...

Comment: Anything wrong with using [hTell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:hTell) ? or `hFileSize` from the same System.IO module ?

Comment: Can json values be divided and span more than one file? Is the size limit a hard limit, or can it be surpassed to fit in the last `MyItem` in a file?

Comment: @jpmarinier, I don't know what Nicolas needed back then, but one problem is that `hTell` only works for seekable handles (actual files, block devices, etc.). If requirements change and the "file" ends up being a pipe sometimes (or some other sort of handle), then all the code will need to be rewritten.

Comment: @dfeuer - Really, I did not consider such a possibility at the time, given that Nicolas mentioned *a file*. On Linux systems, the underlying `lseek` system call may return `ESPIPE` if for some (implementation) reason the stream does not maintain a proper offset. In that case, I would say the least bad option is probably to have the program logic do the counting, possibly using some object wrapper around the OS level file handle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `pipes` anything for this out of the box, but it's easy to write your own `toHandleBounded`.

On each step you check the file size and if it's less than the limit you loop, writing another block to the file.

```hs
toHandleBounded :: MonadIO m => Integer -> Handle -> Consumer' ByteString m ()
toHandleBounded limit hd = do
  current <- liftIO $ hTell hd
  when (current < limit) $ do
    x <- await
    liftIO $ hPut hd x
    toHandleBounded limit hd

main :: IO ()
main =
  withFile "/dev/urandom" ReadMode $ \hIn ->
  withFile "out.txt" WriteMode $ \hOut ->
    runEffect $ P.fromHandle hIn >-> toHandleBounded (1024 * 500 ) hOut
```